# Search string in array

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
[
  {
    "id": 176,
    "aSegments": [
      "CUT_SPECIALITIES1", 
      "CUT_SPECIALITIES2", 
      "CUT_SPECIALITIE2S"
    ],
    "sunFl": true,
    "inPi": false,
    "noBox": 72,
    "prepOven": "15 min / 220C"
  }
]

let searchString = "CUT_SPECIALITIES2"
let products = DataMgr.instance.getProducts(reload: false)
var productsObjectArray = products.filter({
   return  (($0.aSegments?.filter({
       $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased())
   }))?.count)! > 0
})
```

How can I search `CUT_SPECIALITIES2` to find the searched string?

Comment: Try to format you question, please. It's really hard to read the spaghetti in last line :(

Comment: You mean how can you search `aSegments` for `CUT_SPECIALITIES2` don't you?

Comment: this is not searching problem. You should parse this JSon.

Comment: Can you confirm `products` from your `getProducts()` method is returning an array?

Comment: i have parser json in this line: let products = DataMgr.instance.getProducts(reload: false). When I have this code: var productsObjectArray =  $0. prepOven?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))! - work's fine

Comment: yes, I have array in products

Comment: You don't have `description` in your `aSegments` array but you're using `$0.description` in your code.

Comment: fact. But how do you refer to my aSegments in this case? I also have an array?

Comment: What type is `products`? I mean what does the array contain?

Comment: I recommend watching [this WWDC 2017 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/).

Comment: @vadian - yes, it's array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the array I assumed you have :

```
let array = [
[
    "id" : 176,
    "aSegments": [
    "CUT_SPECIALITIES1",
    "CUT_SPECIALITIES2",
    "CUT_SPECIALITIE2S"
    ],
    "sunFl": true,
    "inPi": false,
    "noBox": 72,
    "prepOven": "15 min / 220C"
    ],
[
    "id" : 177,
    "aSegments": [
        "CUT_SPECIALITIES1",
        "CUT_SPECIALITIES2",
        "CUT_SPECIALITIE2S"
    ],
    "sunFl": true,
    "inPi": false,
    "noBox": 73,
    "prepOven": "18 min / 120C"
    ]
]
```

And from this `Array of Dictionaries`, you want to filter the dictionaries based on the `searchString`.

```
let searchString = "CUT_SPECIALITIES2"
let filteredArray = array.filter { (singleProduct) -> Bool in
    guard let aSegments = singleProduct["aSegments"] as? [String] else {
       return false
    }
    return (aSegments.filter({ $0 == searchString }).count > 0)
}
```

This gives an `Array of Dictionaries` which contains your searched string.